# small unit tests , msvc

Tags: c++, c, linux, unit-testing, visual-c++

When I do small unit tests (small exe that calls my function from my library, or calls a piece of code literally embedded before main(), it seems it takes 50 times quicker in Linux than in msvc:

1) In Linux:

> vi test1.c; cut-and-paste includes.
>   cut-and-pase code. add int main(int
>   argc, char **argv) { declare_data;
>   call_my_function(); } :wq! cc test1.c
>   && ./a.out done   every step takes
>   seconds.   if not, helper scripts make
>   it seconds.

2) In msvc:

> create console project. until project
>   creation is finished, it is already
>   more time than whole (1). paste code.
>   fiddle with project settings. try to
>   pass argv. try to pass different argv.

It seems everything is x10 times much slower than in Linux.

In your experience, how small unittests can be created and done really quickly -- in seconds -- in msvc ?

Comment: You forgot the twenty years it takes to become proficient with `vi` :-)

Comment: Do you really want to test/use your libraries using Visual C++, or just test your library on Windows platform?

Comment: the middle part of your MSVC description seems subjective (and flamebait, tbh.). if you want to compare apples to apples, then can we please assume that you either know the relative file paths in *both* cases, or in *neither*? If you're proficient in one tool, and incompetent in the other, then guess what, the first one will always turn out to be more efficient. I'm tempted to downvote your question because of that, which is a shame because the actual question is a good one.

Comment: @jalf. ok removed piece about cwd. Although it is true: in Linux, *I* choose cwd. In msvc, *it* chooses cwd, not I.

Comment: @Ozair: what do you suggest, cygwin/gcc ?

Comment: @Andrei: yes cygwin or `MinGW`

Comment: @Andrei: Yes, but then you're comparing an OS and an IDE, which is hardly fair. In Windows, *you* choose cwd as well. And in Eclipse you don't.

Comment: Apart from that, MSVC (and any other IDE) does allow you to choose cwd. It's just a bit more work to do so. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing is stopping you from compiling and running your MSVC code from the command line. The actual compiler is a command-line tool, so if the IDE is getting in your way, just bypass it. You could even find a Windows port of Vi, and you'd have pretty much exactly the same workflow as on Linux.

But *if* you choose to use a heavy-duty IDE which is designed for working with large code bases, then yes, there'll be quite a bit of overhead.

Unless you write a MSVC addin to make it faster and easier to do these things. (And if you do, please make it public, because a lot of us would find it useful. ;))

Comment: In addition take a look at msbuild and how it deals with the new vcxproj files. You can use it to build .vcxproj and .sln files from the command-line and perhaps easily add a new .vcxproj for your test.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual C++ only for building your test(s), you can use [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your after a VC++ solution, but for others who happen across this question there is the Temporary Projects feature of Visual Studio. Only certain project templates support this, not any c++ that I can find. You could create your own template? See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165252%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for more information on configuring Temporary Projects, it is available in 2005 to 2010 Visual Studios.

Comment: Hilariously, C++ and .NET projects use completely different infrastructure for this. There's no such thing as a C++ project template. VC++ uses a 15-year old COM/Javascript-based monstrosity to generate project files, and so creating your own template would involve quite a bit of work.